# Discord not defined error in visual studio code. What can I do to fix my code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basically the bot wouldn't turn on and every time I entered `node .` into the terminal I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Izzabell\Downloads\discord-bot\index.js:1:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

If anyone could help, here is a screenshot and the exact code that i have used.

```js
var Discord = require(discord.js);
var bot = new Discord.Client ();
const token = 'Enter token here';

bot.on('ready', () =>{    
   console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on ('message', msg=>{
   if (msg.content === "boomer"){     
      msg.reply ('Im not a boomer >:(');
   }
})

bot.login(token);
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aidrG.png I have a link to the code's screenshot, and I copied and pasted the code here. In the screenshot the blocked out area is my token and I put enter token here where the token should go. In the actual code the correct token is inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var Discord = require('discord.js');
make sure you add the two ' in the require

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. It's late. I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: Ok that was an error in the code but the issue was something connected to discord.js. I thought it was downloaded but I redownload it and redid the code and it worked. Tbh I have no clue what I did. Lol. Ty for the help.